# Create Email Alias for Public Calendar in Exchange 2003

Tags: exchange, exchange-2003, public-folders, calendar

We've recently re-created a public calendar on our Exchange Server 2003 after our previous instance of exchange crashed. We call the calendar `DevTeam` since its for our development team to post public team-focused meetings. We used to have an email alias for this calendar, something like `devteam@oursite.com`. We were able to use this alias to create a personal meeting in our own calendar and when inviting `devteam@oursite.com` (in the **To** field) it would automatically go into the DevTeam public calendar. How can I setup this email alias for this calendar if the calendar already exists?

Also, this is very similar to having a "resource calendar" that auto-accepts invites, but this is not a resource, its just a public calendar.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little confused as to what you mean by "How can I setup this email alias for this calendar if the calendar already exists?" The calendar has to exist in order for you to assign an email address to it. At any rate, you mail enable a PF from within ESM (Exchange System Manager).

Comment: I mean I don't want to have to delete it and re-create it again to set the email address. I'll take look at ESM on the server, thanks.

Comment: Mail Enabling it was the solution. This also helped me: http://www.msexchange.org/articles/mf021.html